# thymeleaf can be like jsp use <jsp:include page>?

Tags: spring, jsp, thymeleaf

in jsp , we can used:

index.jsp

```
<body>
    <div>header</div>
   <jsp:include page="/menus"></jsp:include>
   <div>bottom</div>
<body>
```

MenuController.java

```
@Controller
public class MenuController{
    @GetMapping("/menus")
    public String menus(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("menuList",list);
        return "/menu/menu_page";
    }
}
```

/menu/menu_page.jsp

```
<c:forEach items="${menuList}" var="item" varStatus="index">
    .........
</c:foreach>
```

Now, in Thymeleaf can be like that? Include controller url?
I use Thymeleaf's `<th:replace>` and `<th:include>` both can't do it.

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are facing? Its quite hard to understand your requirement here. Please elaborate and post error stack if possible.

Comment: Do you want to include something in another page or do you want the forEach loop?

Comment: have you looked at `th:fragment`?  I'm thinking that's what you're writing about.

Comment: See the links: https://github.com/ultraq/thymeleaf-layout-dialect  and   https://spring.io/blog/2012/10/30/spring-mvc-from-jsp-and-tiles-to-thymeleaf/